# How to query (SQL) a variable amount of user input without rewriting multiple SQL statements

Tags: python, html, mysql, sql, flask

I am creating a web app (using Flask) in which a user can select and input variables that will then produce an output from a dataset depending on the chosen variables. These possible variables can be seen in the HTML POST form below and are fed through to the back-end to allow the SQL query seen in the other code block.

The **issue that I am having is** that when a user selects some of the input variables but leaves others blank, the query returns all of the data.

For example, if the value 'Financial Crime' is selected from one of the drop-downs in the form but no other dropdown/text input is filled, the query returns all possible results.
Whereas the outcome I want is for the query to return all rows with Category=Financial Crime.

I am aware I could write an `if` statement that excludes any input variable with value `''` but this would require re-writing the query for each possible outcome and I am sure there must be a route to do this in a simpler, more optimised way.

HTML:

```
<form method="POST">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <p>Enter Company/Product name:</p>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <br><br>

                    <div class="col">
                        <p>Enter Keywords (delimited by comma):</p>
                        <input type="text" name="keywords" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <br>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm text-left">
                        <label for="category">Choose a category: </label>
                    <br>
                        <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value="">Select Category</option>
                            <option value="Financial Crime">Financial Crime</option>
                            <option value="Regulatory Change">Regulatory Change</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm text-center">
                        <label for="maturity">Choose maturity: </label>
                    <br>
                        <select name="maturity" id="maturity">
                            <option value="">Select Maturity</option>
                            <option value="Incumbent">Incumbent</option>
                            <option value="Challenger">Challenger</option>
                            <option value="New kid">New kid</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm text-right">
                        <label for="under_tech">Choose underlying tech: </label>
                            <br>
                            <select name="under_tech" id="under_tech">
                                <option value="">Select Underlying Tech</option>
                                <option value="AI/ML">AI/ML</option>
                                <option value="Cloud">Cloud</option>
                                <option value="Blockchain">Blockchain</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br><br>
                <div class="row float-right">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Search">
                </div>
            </form>
```

Python (Flask)/SQL :

```
@app.route('/advancedsearch', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def advancedsearch():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category = request.form.get('category')
        maturity = request.form.get('maturity')
        under_tech = request.form.get('under_tech')
        keywords = request.form.get('keywords')
        name = request.form.get('name')
        attribs = [name,keywords,category,maturity,under_tech]

        with db.connect() as conn:
            # Query to find products with selected attributes
            qry = """SELECT CompanyName,ProductName,Category,CompanyWebsite,Logo
                    FROM directory_data.full_dataset
                    WHERE Company_description LIKE %s
                    AND Underlying_Tech LIKE %s
                    AND Company_Maturity LIKE %s
                    AND Category LIKE %s
                    AND CompanyName LIKE %s OR ProductName LIKE %s"""
            results = conn.execute(qry, ("%"+attribs[1]+"%","%"+attribs[4]+"%","%"+attribs[3]+"%","%"+attribs[2]+"%","%"+attribs[0]+"%","%"+attribs[0]+"%")).fetchall()

        if results:
            return render_template('advancedsearch.html', results=results, attribs=attribs)
        else:
            error = 'Results not found'
            return render_template('advancedsearch.html', error=error, attribs=attribs)
    return render_template('advancedsearch.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view, assign the wildcard `%` as a default value for any variable that is missing or empty:

```
category = request.form.get('category') or '%'
maturity = request.form.get('maturity') or '%'
etc.
```

Also, this becomes unneccessary:

```
"%"+attribs[1]+"%"
```

You can just use `attribs[1]`, because `LIKE` already does substring matching. 
 `CompanyName LIKE apple` is exactly the same as `CompanyName LIKE %apple%`.